# IE7 CSS bug aligning <img> with text in a <ul>

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-7

I've been banging my ahead on this IE7 bug for the last few days and it's time to resort to the mind of the crowd.

I have the following HTML and CSS: http://beerpla.net/for_www/ie7_test/test.html

The goal is to have a `<ul>`, with each `<li>` containing a small icon and some text. Multiline text would be aligned to itself and not wrap under the image.

I've tried using `float:left` on the image and a bunch of other things, and finally I thought the `position:absolute` would work for sure but in IE7 I consistently see the text pop off to the next line and get misaligned with the image:

[image]

This is what I expect it to look like:

[image]

I even tried to make the div `display:inline` which kind of worked but then started wrapping under the image for long lines, so it was no good. `zoom:1` also produced a similar effect.

I'm at a loss at the moment. This code works fine in all other browsers. IE7 is a special, very special child.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**Edit:** If you have IE8, you can emulate IE7 by pressing F12 and then Alt-7.

Comment: IE8 in compat mode is not the same as IE7--wouldn't debug in that.

Comment: You can actually switch it to IE 7 Browser Mode from IE8 Compatibility - it's going to render just like IE7. In any case, I also have multiple IE emulators and they all produce the same outcome.

Comment: I actually get it in plain ol' IE8, too.

Comment: Hrm, my IE8 shows the same as Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the `<img>` tag into the `<div>` fixes the issue. Still unknown to me why IE7 does what it does.

Answer (score 2):

instead of putting the image as an element, try using background property. like so

```
ul li { background url(path to image) 0 0 no-repeat; padding: 0 0 0 20px; }
```

note: you might have to adjust the padding to suit the distance you want to maintain between the image and text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using padding on the li instead of margin on the div. If display:inline worked, it's probably IE choking on working out the div's box model in some arcane way: padding on the li and maybe display:inline on the div may iron it out.

Comment: That did it! I haven't seen a more ridiculous behavior from a browser in a while. I'd still like some explanation on why it doesn't work the other ways, especially position:absolute though, and maybe get a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to floating your image left, and then add `overflow: hidden;` to the div. The text will no longer wrap below the image, and there are no side-effects unless you are trying to position content from inside the div out (don't see that here). Completely compatible cross-browser. With IE6 you simply need to add [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) by any means to get the same effect.